# How to change a mongo-spark connection configuration from a databricks python notebook

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I succeeded at connecting to mongodb from spark, using the [mongo-spark connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark) from a databricks notebook in python.

Right now I am configuring the mongodb uri in an environment variable, but it is not flexible, since I want to change the connection parameter right in my notebook.

I read in the [connector documentation](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/doc/2-configuring.md#mongo-spark-connector-configuration) that it is possible to override any values set in the SparkConf.

How can I override the values from python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to set anything in the SparkConf beforehand*. 
You can pass any [configuration options](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/blob/master/doc/2-configuring.md#input-configuration) to the DataFrame Reader or Writer eg:

```
df = sqlContext.read \ 
    .option("uri", "mongodb://example.com/db.coll) \    
    .format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource") \
    .load()
```

* This was added in 0.2